# Getting errors on startup of GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, mac

I downloaded the Mac/Intel chip binary for GRASS 8.3 and put it in my Applications folder.  On startup, I am seeing this in the terminal--

```
MacBook-Pro:~ me$ /Applications/GRASS-8.3.app/Contents/MacOS/Grass.sh
Rebuilding Addon HTML manual pages index...
cp: directory /Users/me/Library/GRASS/8.3/Modules/docs/html does not exist
cp: directory /Users/me/Library/GRASS/8.3/Modules/docs/html does not exist
cp: directory /Users/me/Library/GRASS/8.3/Modules/docs/html does not exist
/Applications/GRASS-8.3.app/Contents/MacOS/build_html_user_index.sh: line 104: cd: /Users/me/Library/GRASS/8.3/Modules/docs/html: No such file or directory
Rebuilding Addon menu...
/Applications/GRASS-8.3.app/Contents/MacOS/build_gui_user_menu.sh: line 58: cd: /Users/me/Library/GRASS/8.3/Modules/bin: No such file or directory
Starting GRASS GIS...
```

and then it displays the GUI, but there is no world map.
When I started it up a few days ago, the GUI started up with the world map just fine.   (I generally try to build things from source but wanted to try a binary first to save time.).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what's going on in the Data pane (should be on the top left). Perhaps you switched your current project (location). If you want to see the world map  again, try to find project world_latlon_wgs84 and double click at vector map country_boundaries to display it.

Comment: Thanks.  That works.  I am hoping to learn how to display meteorological data and wondered if there is a tutorial for that for grass version 8.3.0?